# Pandas drop duplicates and replace the value by the nanmean of the duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (index = date) that I create by appending 4 dataframes. Because of that I have duplicates in my index, with often the same day having 3 NaNs and 1 value.
My goal is to upsample this dataframe to daily frequency (`df = df.resample('1D)`), but before that I have to drop the duplicates.

I would like to drop the time duplicates, but according to 2 conditions:

- For the same day, if we have at least 1 value, calculate the nanmean of the values and drop the rest.
- For the same day, if we only have NaNs, then put a NaN in the row we keep.

I guessed that using np.nanmean() would cover these two conditions (returns a NaN when there are no values, and the mean of the values otherwise).

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pt0': [nan, -42.0, nan, nan, -26.0, nan, nan, nan, 0.0, -10.0]}, 
             index=['1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064', '1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064',
                    '1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000', '1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000',
                    '1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000', '1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000',
                    '1984-09-06 00:00:00.080000000', '1984-09-06 00:00:00.080000000',
                    '1984-09-06 00:00:00.271999936', '1984-09-06 00:00:00.271999936'])
```

```
df = 
                                Pt0
1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064   NaN
1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064 -42.0
1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000   NaN
1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000   NaN
1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000 -26.0
1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000   NaN
1984-09-06 00:00:00.080000000   NaN
1984-09-06 00:00:00.080000000   NaN
1984-09-06 00:00:00.271999936   0
1984-09-06 00:00:00.271999936   -10

df_dropped = 
                               Pt0
1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064 -42.0
1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000   NaN
1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000 -26.0
1984-09-06 00:00:00.080000000 -5.0
```

I tried with `df = df.groupby('Pt0').mean().reset_index()` but it ends up skipping the NaNs, I guess it would work if `df.groupby()` had a `nanmean()` function.

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert the index to datetime objects. Then you can `groupby` the index and transform `np.nanmean`; then `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
out = df.groupby(level=0)['Pt0'].transform(np.nanmean).drop_duplicates().to_frame()
```

Output:

```
                                  Pt0
0 1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064 -42.0
1 1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000   NaN
2 1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000 -26.0
3 1984-09-06 00:00:00.271999936  -5.0
```