# Pandas upsample and nearest interpolation give only NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe (`df`, time as index and 1 column 'Pt0') that I want to upsample and interpolate with "nearest neighbor" method.
I have 2 issues:

1. When I compute `df = df.upsample('1D')`, I get an object core.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler which keeps me from recovering the values of my column (but I can get the index) while I only want a dataframe as output. What I don't understand is that applying this command to other dataframes usually gives me a dataframe, not that "core" object.
2. If I apply the upsampling and interpolation directly: `df = df.resample('1D').interpolate(method='nearest')` I only obtain NaNs while before I had NaNs and values.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, and I wasn't able to understand why a "core" object is created while this same method (`df.resample('1D')`) gave me dataframes in other cases.
How can I solve this problem ?

Ps: df does not have duplicates in the index because it was computed specifically to avoid any ([Pandas drop duplicates and replace the value by the nanmean of the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900618/pandas-drop-duplicates-and-replace-the-value-by-the-nanmean-of-the-duplicates)).

Here is the dataframe:

```
df
Out[174]: 
                                 Pt0
1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064  -42.0
1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000    NaN
1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000  -26.0
1984-10-08 00:00:00.336000064  -12.0
1984-10-16 00:00:00.352000000   -5.0
                             ...
2021-04-05 08:48:28.559141120 -248.0
2021-04-05 08:48:29.059141120 -318.0
2021-04-19 20:36:46.060141056 -311.0
2021-05-04 03:02:44.279659008 -254.0
2021-05-29 02:55:17.930625024 -286.0

[529 rows x 1 columns]
```

Code to reproduce my issues:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Pt0': [np.nan, -42.0, np.nan, np.nan, -26.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.0, -10.0]}, 
                 index=['1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064', '1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064',
                        '1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000', '1984-07-20 00:00:00.176000000',
                        '1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000', '1984-07-28 00:00:00.192000000',
                        '1984-09-06 00:00:00.080000000', '1984-09-06 00:00:00.080000000',
                        '1984-09-06 00:00:00.271999936', '1984-09-06 00:00:00.271999936'])
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    df = df.groupby(level=0)['Pt0'].transform(np.nanmean).drop_duplicates().to_frame()
    df2 = df.resample('1D')
    df3 = df.resample('1D').interpolate('nearest')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong but you missed one step before. You need to align your source index to your target index (days): `1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064` is not equal to `1984-06-10` i.e. `1984-06-10 00:00:00.000000000`. That's why you can see your original values in the Resampler object but not in the final result:

```
>>> list(df.resample('D'))[0]
(Timestamp('1984-06-10 00:00:00', freq='D'),
                                 Pt0
 1984-06-10 00:00:00.096000064 -42.0)
```

What you need is to apply an operation between `resample` and `interpolate`. In the present case, take the `first` value is sufficient but imagine you have multiple values for a same day, how Pandas can guess which value to pick?.
In fact, before upsampling to get extra days you need to downsampling your intraday values.

**Step-1:**

```
>>> df.resample('D').first()  # or mean() or whatever you want
             Pt0
1984-06-10 -42.0  # <- now the index and values are aligned
1984-06-11   NaN
1984-06-12   NaN
1984-06-13   NaN
1984-06-14   NaN
...          ...
1984-09-02   NaN
1984-09-03   NaN
1984-09-04   NaN
1984-09-05   NaN
1984-09-06  -5.0

[89 rows x 1 columns]
```

**Step-2:**

```
>>> df.resample('D').first().interpolate('time')  # or nearest or ...
                  Pt0
1984-06-10 -42.000000
1984-06-11 -41.666667
1984-06-12 -41.333333
1984-06-13 -41.000000
1984-06-14 -40.666667
...               ...
1984-09-02  -7.100000
1984-09-03  -6.575000
1984-09-04  -6.050000
1984-09-05  -5.525000
1984-09-06  -5.000000

[89 rows x 1 columns]
```

You can do the same with `groupby` which can be more intuitive at all because it's more natural: *I want to group my values per day then compute the mean and finally fill missing values by interpolate with a X method*

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean().interpolate('time')
                  Pt0
1984-06-10 -42.000000
1984-06-11 -41.666667
1984-06-12 -41.333333
1984-06-13 -41.000000
1984-06-14 -40.666667
...               ...
1984-09-02  -7.100000
1984-09-03  -6.575000
1984-09-04  -6.050000
1984-09-05  -5.525000
1984-09-06  -5.000000

[89 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: That was an interesting problem. I hope my explanation are clear enough :)

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works very well and I really appreciate the detailed explanation :) 
I have one more question though: by using "df.resample.first()", how come in the first iteration of df, we don't end up with a NaN for 1984-06-10 ? Because when using df.drop_duplicates(), the "first" argument was considering the NaN as the first value, and dumping the value "-42.0".

Comment: In `drop_duplicated`, the "first" argument means the first row encountered whatever the value. For the "first" method of `Resampler` or `Grouper` it's like `.dropna().first()`. Here I used `first` because you have only one value, in real life, `mean` is better even if you have only one value.